# How to show that the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ tensoring itself is isomorphic to the direct sum $K\oplus L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

> **Problem.** Let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Then the following two algebras are isomorphic:$$K\otimes_{\mathbb Q}K\cong K\oplus L.$$

Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field, it can be instantly seen that they are isomorphic as modules. However, I find it difficult to find a correspondence between their bases that also fits their algebra structure. So I would like to ask if we are going to finish this problem by figuring out an appropriate corrspondence between some bases of them, or there is another way for it? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $K$, $(x^3-2)=(x-\sqrt[3]{2}) \cdot f$ for some quadratic polynomial $f$. Note that $K[x]/(f)=L$.

Now we can compute with the Chinese remainder theorem:
$$K\otimes_{\mathbb Q} K = K \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)=K[x]/(x^3-2) = K[x]/(x-\sqrt[3]{2}) \times K[x]/(f) = K \times L.$$

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more why $K\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)=K[x]/(x^3-2)$?

Comment: Tha holds for any ring map. The base change of the polynomial ring is the polynomial ring. Just check the universal properties.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Thanks!